# How to declare a policy class that does nothing to a string, has consistent signature with other policies and is evaluated at compile-time

Tags: c++, string, templates, constexpr, policy-based-design

I am putting together a set of policy classes that operate a number of operations to a string. I would like these policies to be exchangeable, but the "do nothing" policy is problematic too me, as:

1. I don't see how to avoid copy using move semantic while maintaining the same (non-move) interface with the sister policies
2. The compiler should know that the call to the policy can be inlined and evaluated at compile time, but it does not accept `constexpr` because the return type is a string.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include<regex>
#include<cassert>

///
/// @brief Do not change anything
///
struct identity
{
    static std::string edit(std::string&& s) // can not use constexpr: return type not a literal
    {
    return std::move(s);
    }
};
///
/// @brief Template class.
///
template<unsigned int N>
struct remove_comments_of_depth
{};
///
/// @brief Do not remove anything
///
template<> struct remove_comments_of_depth<0> : identity
{};
///
/// @brief Remove all comments substrings contained between square brackets
///
/// @note Assumes that text is well formatted so there are no such things like [[]] or unclosed bracket
///
template<> struct remove_comments_of_depth<1>
{
    static std::string edit(const std::string& s)
    {
        return std::regex_replace(s, std::regex(R"(\[[^()]*\])"), "");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string s = "my_string[this is a comment]";
    auto copy = s;
    assert(remove_comments_of_depth<1>::edit(s) == "my_string");
    assert(remove_comments_of_depth<0>::edit(std::move(copy)) == s); // <<< how to avoid this call to std::move
}
```

What is the "standard" way to go in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is reduce unnecessary copy and don't use `std::move` when calling `edit`. Why not just return a const reference?

```cpp
struct identity
{
    static const std::string& edit(const std::string& s) {
        return s;
    }
};

std::string s = "my_string[this is a comment]";
assert(remove_comments_of_depth<0>::edit("my_string[this is a comment]") == "my_string[this is a comment]");
assert(remove_comments_of_depth<0>::edit(s) == "my_string[this is a comment]");
```

See [Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f7YossWYM)

As to your second question, since C++20, `std::string` can be a literal type.

```cpp
struct identity
{
    constexpr static std::string edit(std::string&& s) {
        return s;
    }
};

static_assert(remove_comments_of_depth<0>::edit("my_string[this is a comment]") == "my_string[this is a comment]");
```

It's totally fine in C++20, see [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xraEKEs1W).

But since your variable `s` can't be `constexpr` (it's created at run-time), there's no big help here.